# Way to fade in an element while moving down/translating from the top?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, fade, translate

I'm trying to figure out a way to have the first header and paragraph of a specific web page to simultaneously translate into place from the top while fading in.

I've looked into using @keyframes, which definitely seems like the solution. But with that said, I haven't been able to figure out a way to translate the elements without specifying a set distance to translate. Instead, I simply want to translate the elements from the top, into their current place (or where they would otherwise be).

Here is my site for reference: http://thefloodplains.com/About.html. I currently have the second section to Fade In (with no translation), but I want the top section to fade in from the top.

Basically what I want to do is this: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_keyframes, but without a specified amount of pixels to translate - I simply want to translate it from the top into its current location.

Here is another similar example, but I don't want a fade-out effect (the first one): https://codepen.io/kianoshp/pen/PPeWzb.

```
@keyframes topFadeOut {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3rem;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  75% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Any and all help would be deeply appreciated. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Hi. Would you be able to show the HTML of your code also?

Comment: What you want is not technically possible. You can't transition an unknown distance. You have to determine the distance, using either CSS or JavaScript and pass it to browser so it could be performed.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes topFadeOut {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3rem;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

h {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #00A5D1;
  font-family: 'Gentium Basic', Verdana, 'Slabo 27px', 'Vollkorn', serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  animation-name: topFadeOut;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

```html
  <section class="box">
    <h>The Floodplains</h>
  </section>
```